# 4 Centered Images HTML/ CSS BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css

[image: I need 4 images to be centered in the page without spaces, and responsive , I've Tried many ways but can't get it to work right.]
--FIRST IMAGE IS DESIRE OUTPUT---

I got it to work on my screen but when I put it on bigger monitor doesn't seem to scale right. Any Recommendations ?

```
<div style="margin-left: 100px;margin-right: 100px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -1.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img s src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -2.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -3.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -5.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: This is what i got with this code]
This is what I get with this other code, centers but can't get rid the spaces.

---THIS IS WHAT I GET---

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 70px;">
    <!-- column -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5cols wow bounceInLeft ">
        <div class="thumbnail ">
            <img src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -1.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- column -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5cols wow bounceInLeft ">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -2.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- column -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5cols wow swing ">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -3.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- column -->

    <!-- column -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5cols wow bounceInRight ">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -5.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you also post your css, also, Im not really sure what you are asking? Centered horizontally? Vertically? Is the screenshot visually correct or incorrect?

Comment: is the width and height of image same for all?

Comment: What is your desired output ? did you try using the class `img-responsive` for the img tag /

Comment: @SahilDhir yes all images exactly same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `inline-block` elements, I have created `inline-block` class to wrap `img` and gave `text-center` class to `row` to align images in center.

```css
.row-custom .inline-block{
  display:inline-block;
}
.row-custom .inline-block img{
  max-width:100px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row row-custom text-center">
  <div class="inline-block">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <img s src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if the window gets bigger, the images get spaces in between

Comment: Updated answer, check once

Comment: Thanks. Finally got it, I got the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Do these 3 things to achieve the desire result-**

**1.** **Add** `.img-responsive` class to your **img tags** as its a way to make **images responsive** in **bootstrap framework**. You can also check this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) for reference .

**2.** Add width="100%" to images to take up full space available in the image.

**3.** Add nopadding class to columns so that it will remove the padding space.

> Update your code as below:

```css
.nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" width="100%" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding">
    <img s src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 nopadding">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive" width="100%">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That class does make the images responsive, but only when the window is small, for example: [link](http://imgur.com/a/RE1IN) and if the window gets bigger: [link](http://imgur.com/a/FD7SX) the images get spaces I dont want those spaces. Thanks for the help

Comment: no issue I have updated my answer .. hope it can help

Comment: I would but Im not 15 rep yet, I really appreciate all your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to change or add more into CSS, You can use the Bootstrap class:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/NUESTROS EVENTOS -5.png">
    </div>
</div>
```